# Convert datetime UTC format and then calculate timedelta

Tags: python

Been trying to use datetime in UTC/ISO format, which outputs a very finicky format, and then create a time range of 15 min and 1 hour past. Here's what I have so far:

1. Was able to successfully format the time according to specifications.

   `now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'`

Output:

```
2022-12-16T21:54:12.184Z
<class 'str'>
```

So far so good. Now, if I try to use it along with timedelta, I get a TypeError:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON\tiny3.py", line 27, in <module>        
    past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I then tried using the strptime() function, but it complains again because of an unsupported operand.

```
now_to_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(now,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Output:

```
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Here is the entire script:

```
now = (datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z')
now_to_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(now,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
past15min = (now_to_datetime - timedelta(minutes=15))
print(past15min)
```

These attempts, among several others have proven to be a failure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `isoformat` until you're ready to print. Leave `now` as a datetime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15)).utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
print(past15min)
```

When you use `isoformat` or `strptime`, you turn `datetime` objects into `string`. As they are turned into `string`, you can't use `timedelta` to calculate time.
So calculate time first before you use methods such as `isoformat` or `strptime`.

Comment: Thank you for both the example and explanation!